# How can you disable "Show Edit History" for a single cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I turned on `Show Edit History` for one cell in a Google Sheet and now I want to turn it off for that one cell.

I can't see any way to do so.  If I right-click on the cell I see `Show Edit History` but it is not a toggle, as I would have hoped.  I don't see anything useful in the menus and web-searching has not been fruitful.

I am not trying to turn off or opt-out of the entire feature.  I only want to  deactivate `show edit history` for a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

Cell edit history isn't a opt-in feature, there isn't a turn on/off setting for it, either a spreadsheet level, neither a cell level.

If you edited a cell after the feature was added by Google to your spreadsheet, it can't be turned off for that cell as well it isn’t possible to turn it off/opt-out.

References

- [Find what's changed in a file](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop) (help article)
- [View the edit history of a cell in Sheets](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/06/edit-history-sheets.html) (feature launch announcement)

Answer (score 0):

> I turned on `Show edit history`

No. You selected the **`Show edit history`** option to view history specific to a single cell. You didn't enable, or turn on, anything.<sup>**¹**</sup>
 <sup>**¹** <sub>*Already noted in [Rubén's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/135209/)*</sub></sup>

#### Sheets Change Logging

From the time it is created, Sheets logs document changes/edits. This continues regardless what option an Editor uses to view this history, or even if the history is never viewed at all.

This history/logging cannot be disabled at a cell, sheet, or document level.

#### Cell-Specific History

The addition of the **`Show edit history`** option provided Editors an efficient way to view the document's history filtered for a specific cell and without needing to leave the document's edit mode.  This option made a lot of sense in contrast to the existing alternatives and simplified the typical Editor's workflow.

For example, prior to the addition of cell-specific history, an Editor could still access that same information via the version history interface with **`Show changes`** selected.  However it required clicking through versions (logged changes grouped by date/time) to find the changes specific to that one cell.

Depending on the total number of changes, the number of changes specific to a cell, and whether the rough date/time of the changes was known, it could easily become very time consuming in the absence of a script or extension.

Additionally, the version history interface is distinct from the document editing mode. In the case where one simply wanted some cell-specific history, this approach was extremely and unnecessarily disruptive to an Editor's workflow.

#### Main Points

1. Sheets logs changes from the time a document is created.
2. There is no way to disable or delete a document's history.
3. Only an Editor can view a document's history.
4. **`See version history`** and **`Show edit history`** both access the same information.

#### New Document = New History

Copying a source document's content to a newly created target will  provide a fresh start.  Both documents will include the same content but the source document's history can't be copied along with its content.

Copying a document (as opposed to its content) achieves the same result. From the list below, "Make a copy" is the best choice for most Editors however all of the listed methods create a new document without any of the original document's history:

1. File > Make a copy
   <sup>*Copied to Google Drive in Sheets format*</sup>
2. File > Email > Email this file > [Choose file type]
   <sup>*File choices:  PDF, ODS, or XLSX* **³**</sup>
3. File > Download > [Choose file type]
   <sup>*File choices: XLSX, ODS, PDF, HTML,CSV, or TSV* **³**</sup>

<sup>**³**</sup> <sup><sub>*See Table*</sub></sup>

| Document | Extension |
| --- | --- |
| Microsoft Excel | XLSX |
| OpenDocument Spreadsheet | ODS |
| PDF Document | PDF |
| Web Page | HTML (ZIP archive) |
| Comma-Seperated Values | CSV |
| Tab-Seperated Values | TSV |